# How to make VS code terminal distinguish between different data types by giving different colours?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I don't want to print colored text in the terminal. I want the Terminal itself to colourise the output based on its data type.

For example:
I'm printing a python variable in VScode terminal, and the output says `123`.
Now I want to know if its a `String` or `Integer`.
I know I can print its data type and check, but its time consuming.
I want to know if there's any way to make VScode terminal to display `string` and `integer` in different `color`.

Code:

```py
n = "123"
print(n)
print(int(n))
```

OUTPUT in VScode Terminal:

```
123
123
```

I'm using Macbook(M1) and my Macbook uses zsh (Z shell) within the terminal.

Comment: use the supplied link and write your own `print` routine that checks the type of the variable and sets the color you want. But be aware that if you don't output on a terminal, using a pipe, you get a lot of garbage in the output stream. You can write a print function that does this for any data structure passed as argument